# How to upgrade SQL Server 2012 to 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database backup that I cannot restore, because it was created with a newer version of SQL Server, error below:

[image]

Here's the info I get in SSMS under Help > About:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio     11.0.7507.2
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools   11.0.7507.2
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)    10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML                            3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                9.11.19041.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                   4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                           6.3.19044
```

What are the steps to take to upgrade my SQL Server and SSMS to 2019? This is a local environment on Windows 10.

Comment: download SQL Server 2019 Installation media and upgrade your current instance or install the new one

Comment: I _assume_ you're using express or developer (in a non-production environment); otherwise you need to buy licences too. Honestly, for the former, there's little reason to not ensure you are upgrading at regular intervals as Express is free. Also, the version of SSMS you want is version 18 (there is not SSMS 2019). There *is* an SSMS 19, but that is currently in preview alongside SQL Server 2022's preview.

Comment: @Larnu, it's the developer version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a backup and you cannot restore it.

First of all, I would check whether this backup works for version 15.00.4153 like it claims. If you have the installer of such a version, then it would make sense to use it (and install it, if necessary) and check the restore operation to see whether it works with that version. If so, use that version and don't look back to your old version. You need to upgrade SQL Server first, and only then you can use the benefits of your newer version.

If the backup cannot be restored even on the newer version, then you are likely dealing with a damaged file. In that case I would try to look at the actual SQL code that would be generated (if available) and detect where the problem occurs.

In the worst-case scenario you can ask the team/person that initially exported their database to export a(nother) SQL file and look for errors manually if it fails to run.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. And I did get an error after installing 2019 and SSMS, I am getting Access Denied when I try to restore, and I am looking into it.  EDIT: that was my rookie mistake, running SSMS as admin resolves the access denied issue. It is restored successfully :D

Comment: @hnnnng so, basically you no longer have the version problem after installing the 2019 version, but you have a new problem about privileges? Maybe you could open SSMS as Administrator?

Comment: Correct. It's all good now :D